# Show that the equation has no integer solutions

Tags: modular-arithmetic, roots

I am trying to show that the equation $7x^5-23x^2+2x-8=0$ has no integer solutions i.e $x$ belonging to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Now I am aware calculus can be used to show there is no real root except the rational between $1$ and $2$ but I'd like to use modular arithmetic to show the lack of integer solutions.

What I've tried so far is:

1. Assume $k$ belonging to $\mathbb{Z}$ is a root
2. $k(7k^4-23k+2)=8$ which shows that $8$ must divide either $x$ or $7x^4-23x+2$
3. Take $k=8m$ and insert
4. ?

Now this might be totally the wrong approach.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the rational roots theorem, can't you? According to that, all integer roots must be divisors of $8$.

Comment: @Moo corrected, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider modulo $3$

Comment: @Moo no, step 2 is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use modular arithmetic to show the lack of integer solutions:

$$7x^5-23x^2+2x-8\equiv x+x^2+2x+1\equiv x^2+1\not\equiv0\pmod3$$

Comment: Thank you, how do I know to choose (mod 3)?

Comment: @napadia For me, I simply tried trial and error, considering (mod n) for various small positive integers $n$.  Then, I accidentally noticed that [7 + 2] = 9.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit further?

Comment: @napadia See my answer.  First of all, when considering a (mod 3) argument, all you have to check are $\{-1,0,+1\}.$  Clearly $1^5 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $0^5 \equiv 0\pmod{3}$, so the only hard part here was recognizing that $(-1)^5 \equiv (-1)\pmod{3}.$  Then, the next challenge was recognizing that $(-23) \equiv (1)\pmod{3}$, so the problem reduced to showing that $x^2$ can't be congruent to 8 $\pmod{3}.$

Comment: @napadia:  are you asking for more explanation of why I chose $3$ or why $3$ works (i.e., more details for the string of congruences in my answer)?

Comment: Good question.  Personally, I wasted time first trying (mod 5) and (mod 8) arguments.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Why you chose 3, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @napadia:  I just tried small moduli.  $7$ would work too

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm sorry but how do I know what moduli don't work?

Comment: @napadia:  if $7x^5-23x^2+2x-8\equiv0\pmod p$ for some $x$ between $0$ and $p-1$, then $p$ doesn't work as a modulus for this purpose

Answer (score 3):

$k(7k^4-23k+2)=8$

Start from here, you first would notice if $k$ is integer, then $7k^4-23k+2$ is also integer.

Therefore $k$ can be $1,2,4,8,-1,-2,-4,-8$. You should check each of these case and calculate $7k^4-23k+2$ and confirm $k(7k^4-23k+2)$ is not $8$.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, a (mod 3) argument will work here.

$7x^5 + 2x \equiv 0 \pmod{3},~$ precisely because $x^5 \equiv x\pmod{3}.$

Then the problem reduces to noticing that $-23x^2 \equiv x^2 \pmod{3}$, which can't be congruent to $2 \pmod{3}.$